# Save IDLE's output from a freezed window shell

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-idle

I run a script for several hours and I print the results (by mistake) on the IDLE shell window. Now, the window is freezed and I cannot write anything there to export the data (a list of lists) to a file so I can save them.

Is there any way to access the memory and export the variable I want or I need to run the script again?

I am on Ubuntu with Python 2.7.6

Comment: run it again, and make sure it saves to a file or db this time.

Comment: I had an export to a csv but it raised an error due to a unicode character error. Didn't expect that. So, there isn't a way to save it now :(

Comment: try to parse the file. if you saved it correctly then you should be able to read it back.

Comment: You should have been able to cut output from Idle Shell.  You might needed to kill the separate user process first with ^C (Keyboard Interrupt), Shell -> Restart Shell, or even with kill <process #> at a console command line.  If the Idle process itself were frozen for reasons other than waiting on the user process, there is likely nothing to do.